# Long title runs off page

Tags: boxes, gnuplot

I'm making a graph in using `gnuplot` and have converted the `eps` to `pdf`, so I have `.tex` file and `pdf` file. Usual they are great except this time the title in the title runs off the page, the title is a line of the `.tex` file.

```
  \put(3940,4709){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE}}%
```

I've tried using "\n" but pdflatex compiler doesn't like this argument.

```
  \put(3940,4709){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE,\n REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE}}%
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `\parbox{desired width}{REALLY LONG TITLE …}` instead of the `\makebox`?

Comment: I will try that when I get home from work. and if it doesn't work I'll try an upload an example.

Comment: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
     <to be read again> 
                        \relax 
     l.115     \gplbacktext
                      
I've started to get this error

Comment: How do I make code in comments?

Comment: @JoshuaSiret: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5764) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863/5764), they'll be marked as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\put(3940,5009){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE,}}%
\put(3940,4709){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE, REALLY LONG TITLE!}}%
```

I ended up making another box "300" units higher and inserting half the title there. It looks really good, everything is still centered which didn't happen with parbox{}{} and was easier to implement.

Though thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for their help.